# How to upload python package in Github?

Tags: git

I am creating a Flask Website impurity_calculator_app, which is using the imp_calc package.
When I push the repo after making changes in imp_calc it isn't recognised.
My folder structure.

```
impurity_calculator_app
├── imp_calc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── register.html
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── routes.py
├── run.py
│── module2.py
└── calc.py
```

I can see the changes are not staged, Git Push shows everything up to date and git add doesn't respond.

On doing

```
git commit -m"some message": 

Changes not staged for commit:
modified : imp_calc
modified : .gitignore
```

Comment: If the change not getting recognized under `imp_calc` directory then you should if the directory is being ignore in `.gitignore` file. If `imp_calc` exist in `.gitignore` file then remove the line and type `git add .gitignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git add` command needs an argument which defines what to add. You can use `git add .` in order to add all the files and directories in your current working directory of your terminal. To add a specific file use something like `git add imp_calc/__init__.py` (provided you are in the root directory of your project "impurity_calculator_app"). After you did that you can commit and finally push.

If you already knew that could it be the imp_calc directory is in the .gitignore file?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention. The `git add` command doesn't output anything to the console.